# Drop down menu disappears on hover asp.net website

Tags: html, css

Please help me if any one have solution of this. The drop down menu was working proper earlier. But now it is disappear on mouse hover.

**Below is the revised code.**

```css
CSS:

.navbar-nav .dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  transform: translateX(0);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease 0s, transform 0.4s ease 0s, -webkit-transform 0.4s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease 0s, transform 0.4s ease 0s, -webkit-transform 0.4s ease 0s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.4s ease 0s, transform 0.4s ease 0s, -webkit-transform 0.4s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease 0s, transform 0.4s ease 0s, -webkit-transform 0.4s ease 0s;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  top: 100%;
  margin-top: -4px;
}

.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu>li>a+.dropdown-menu {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.1s ease 0s, transform 0.1s ease 0s, -webkit-transform 0.1s ease 0s !important;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.1s ease 0s, transform 0.1s ease 0s, -webkit-transform 0.1s ease 0s !important;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.1s ease 0s, transform 0.1s ease 0s, -webkit-transform 0.1s ease 0s !important;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.1s ease 0s, transform 0.1s ease 0s, -webkit-transform 0.1s ease 0s !important;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

header .header-cart-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  right: -20px;
  top: -5000px;
  width: 350px;
  padding: 35px 32px 25px;
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transform: translateX(20px);
  text-align: left;
}

.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: -110px;
  transform: translateX(20px);
  bottom: auto !important;
  left: 50%;
  width: 220px;
  display: block !important;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: -5000px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
HTML:

<div id="slidemenu">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="close-menu"><i class="icon-close-cross"></i></div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li id="imenu1"><a href="Default.aspx"><span>Dashboard</span></a></li>
        <li id="imenu2" class="dropdown">
          <a href="CarManage.aspx" data-toggle="dropdown" data-submenu=""><span>My Cars</span><span class="ecaret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="CarAdd.aspx">Add Car</a></li>
            <li><a href="CarManage.aspx">View Car</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li id="imenu3"><a href="JobCardAdd.aspx"><span>Create Service Request</span></a></li>
        <li id="imenu4"><a href="JobCardList.aspx"><span>Services List</span></a></li>

        <li id="imenu5" class="dropdown" style="float: right;">
          <a href="Profile.aspx" data-toggle="dropdown" data-submenu=""><span><i class="icon icon-people-1"></i>Profile</span><span class="ecaret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="Profile.aspx">Manage</a></li>
            <li><a href="Logout.aspx">Logout</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please help me if any one have solution of this. The drop down menu was working proper earlier. But now it is disappear on mouse hover.

```css
.navbar-nav .dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  transform: translateX(0);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease 0s, transform 0.4s ease 0s, -webkit-transform 0.4s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease 0s, transform 0.4s ease 0s, -webkit-transform 0.4s ease 0s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.4s ease 0s, transform 0.4s ease 0s, -webkit-transform 0.4s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease 0s, transform 0.4s ease 0s, -webkit-transform 0.4s ease 0s;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  top: 100%;
  margin-top: -4px;
}

.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu>li>a+.dropdown-menu {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.1s ease 0s, transform 0.1s ease 0s, -webkit-transform 0.1s ease 0s !important;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.1s ease 0s, transform 0.1s ease 0s, -webkit-transform 0.1s ease 0s !important;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.1s ease 0s, transform 0.1s ease 0s, -webkit-transform 0.1s ease 0s !important;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.1s ease 0s, transform 0.1s ease 0s, -webkit-transform 0.1s ease 0s !important;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="slidemenu">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="close-menu"><i class="icon-close-cross"></i></div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li id="imenu1"><a href="Default.aspx"><span>Dashboard</span></a></li>
        <li id="imenu2" class="dropdown">
          <a href="CarManage.aspx" data-toggle="dropdown" data-submenu=""><span>My Cars</span><span class="ecaret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="CarAdd.aspx">Add Car</a></li>
            <li><a href="CarManage.aspx">View Car</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li id="imenu3"><a href="JobCardAdd.aspx"><span>Create Service Request</span></a></li>
        <li id="imenu4"><a href="JobCardList.aspx"><span>Services List</span></a></li>

        <li id="imenu5" class="dropdown" style="float: right;">
          <a href="Profile.aspx" data-toggle="dropdown" data-submenu=""><span><i class="icon icon-people-1"></i>Profile</span><span class="ecaret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="Profile.aspx">Manage</a></li>
            <li><a href="Logout.aspx">Logout</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: block;` to `.navbar-nav .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu`

Working example:

```css
.navbar-nav .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
transform: translateX(0);
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease 0s, transform 0.4s ease 0s, -webkit-transform 0.4s ease 0s;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease 0s, transform 0.4s ease 0s, -webkit-transform 0.4s ease 0s;
-ms-transition: opacity 0.4s ease 0s, transform 0.4s ease 0s, -webkit-transform 0.4s ease 0s;
-o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease 0s, transform 0.4s ease 0s, -webkit-transform 0.4s ease 0s;
opacity: 1;
visibility: visible;
top: 100%;
margin-top: -4px;
display: block;

} .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li > a + .dropdown-menu { -webkit-transition: opacity 0.1s ease 0s, transform 0.1s ease 0s, -webkit-transform 0.1s ease 0s !important; -moz-transition: opacity 0.1s ease 0s, transform 0.1s ease 0s, -webkit-transform 0.1s ease 0s !important; -ms-transition: opacity 0.1s ease 0s, transform 0.1s ease 0s, -webkit-transform 0.1s ease 0s !important; -o-transition: opacity 0.1s ease 0s, transform 0.1s ease 0s, -webkit-transform 0.1s ease 0s !important; left: 100%; top: 0; opacity: 0; margin: 0 !important; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="slidemenu">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="close-menu"><i class="icon-close-cross"></i></div>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li id="imenu1"><a href="Default.aspx"><span>Dashboard</span></a></li>
                                <li id="imenu2" class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="CarManage.aspx" data-toggle="dropdown" data-submenu=""><span>My Cars</span><span class="ecaret"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                        <li><a href="CarAdd.aspx">Add Car</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="CarManage.aspx">View Car</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>

                                <li id="imenu3"><a href="JobCardAdd.aspx"><span>Create Service Request</span></a></li>
                                <li id="imenu4"><a href="JobCardList.aspx"><span>Services List</span></a></li>

                                <li id="imenu5" class="dropdown" style="float: right;">
                                    <a href="Profile.aspx" data-toggle="dropdown" data-submenu=""><span><i class="icon icon-people-1"></i>Profile</span><span class="ecaret"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                        <li><a href="Profile.aspx">Manage</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="Logout.aspx">Logout</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Thanks John. I did the same but still it is not working.

Comment: @SpiderCommunicationPvtLtd can you link to the actual website with the issue?  My example is working as intended so I'll need more info to help more.

Comment: Yes sure. I have created a test page for you. http://service.auswideautocare.com.au/test.aspx

Comment: @SpiderCommunicationPvtLtd something is setting your dropdown menu at `top: -5000px;` and its acting weird.  Can you find any code that has `.dropdown:hover` or something regarding the `hover` state of your menu and update your question with that code?  That will help me debug your problem.

Comment: I found 'top: -5000px;' at two places in CSS. I updated the question with revised code.

Comment: @SpiderCommunicationPvtLtd your test site isn't working anymore